# Java pattern matching

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections

The following code takes a file compiled with methods called during an execution.

For example, let us say if a method named "sun.test.class.method1" had been called 100 times, then there would be 100 entries in the file.

The output file consists of method names(which should not repeat) and the number of times they have been called. The output entry for "sun.test.class.method1" would be  {sun.test.class.method1 = 100 }

I want to add one more constraint. If two methods of a same class had been called many a times, example "sun.test.class.method1" 100 times and "sun.test.class.method2" 150 times, then output should be "sun.test.class -> method1=100,method2=150"(i.e.) I just want to write the class name once and then the calculation of method calls.

How to implement this ? Thanks in advance!

```
public class MethodCount {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = null;
    PrintWriter output = null;
    Map<String, Integer> map = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(
                new File("D:\\MethodIn.txt"));
        output = new PrintWriter("D:\\MethodOut.txt");
        map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
    while (input.hasNext()) {enter code here
        String m = input.next();
        if (map.get(m) != null) {
            map.put(m, map.get(m) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(m, 1);
        }
    }
    output.println(map);
    output.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think what you really want is to sort the keys of your `map` before outputting it. I.e. in the output you want methods of the same class to appear next to each other. Right?

Comment: @Daniel: yes!! Under the class name, methods and the number of times they have been invoked.

Comment: Map<ClassName, Map<MethodName, Integer>>

Comment: @SamiKorhonen! Keys are distinct right! I wont be able to store {sun.class1=method1=100,sun.class1=method2=150}